# How do you remove repeated consecutive elements, but not all duplicate elements from a Ruby Array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given the Array:

```
arr = ['a','a','b','b','b','a','c']
```

Is there a quick way in Ruby to remove repeated consecutive elements, but not all duplicate elements like arr.uniq would?  The expected output would be:

```
['a','b','a','c']
```

Here's what I've tried.  It is possible to iterate over the Array as follows, but what is the cleanest way to do this in Ruby?

```
def remove_repeats arr
  new_arr       = []
  last_element  = nil
  arr.each do |x|
    if last_element != x
      new_arr << x
    end
    last_element = x
  end
  new_arr
end

arr = ['a','a','b','b','b','a','c','c']
puts remove_repeats(arr).join(',')

# => a,b,a,c
```

Comment: This perhaps is a duplicate, I was searching for how to operate on the Array class specifically.  The other question talks of the more specific terminology lists, which I could have also searched I guess.  The other question barely uses the term Array (only in a few comments) and it is the class which is actually being used.  That is also why I used Array (with a capital), it is a class.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one

```
arr.chunk_while(&:==).map(&:first)
```

The first step, `arr.chunk_while(&:==)`, makes an array of array of equal values'. You can see the first step's outcome with `arr.chunk_while(&:==).to_a`. The second step, `map(&:first)`, takes the first item for every subarray and at the end it flattens this n-subarray array.

Comment: Thanks!  That is pretty slick, I will leave the question open a bit for any other input but this was the kind of ruby one-liner answer I was expecting would exist.

Comment: Note that since Ruby 2.2 the first step can also be written as `arr.chunk(&:itself)`. Also your solution works fine with `map`, no need to use `flat_map` here.

Comment: if array conatin on single letters then you can use `arr.join.squeeze.split('')` 
or insteatd of chunk while or flat_map use : `arr.chunk(&:itself).map(&:first)`
it is more optimized
Thanks!

Comment: if you have `facets gem` link: https://github.com/rubyworks/facets
then you can simply use `arr.squeeze!`
ref:https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Array:squeeze!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions you all :)

Comment: Thank you all, I am actually using this with words not single characters although it is good to see the single character solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `arr.uniq!`, it removes all duplicates in place.

Comment: The user doesn't want the uniq values. Read the question

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad.